# some confusion about supremum and infimum

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $a_{mn}$ be a double array or real numbers. Define $$A=\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty} \limsup_{m\rightarrow\infty}a_{mn}\\B=\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} \liminf_{m\rightarrow\infty}a_{mn},$$
>
> Then  which one is true?
>
> 1. $A\le B$
> 2. $A\ge B $

My attempt :

I think option $1$ that $A\le B$ is true because the supremum is always greater than then infimum.

Is  this  correct ? Any hints/solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course the supremum is always greater than or equal to the infimum. However, if one has mixtures of $\limsup$ and $\liminf$, it is indecisive which one is greater. For example, let $$
a_{mn} = (-1)^n (1-\frac{1}{2^m}).
$$ Then we have
$$
1=\liminf_{m\to\infty}\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_{mn} >\limsup_{m\to\infty}\liminf_{n\to\infty}a_{mn} =-1
$$ while
$$
-1=\liminf_{n\to\infty}\limsup_{m\to\infty}a_{mn}<\limsup_{n\to\infty}\liminf_{m\to\infty}a_{mn}=1.
$$